# SSIS Derived Column String Concat multiple date expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssis

**Solution**
Literally have to typecast every variable except the literal strings.. wow..

`(DT_STR,30,1252)(
     (DT_STR,3,1252)(DATEDIFF("mi", (DT_DATE)[fnTimeOut], (DT_DATE)[fnTimeIn])/1440) 
     + ":" +
     (DT_STR,3,1252)(DATEDIFF("mi", (DT_DATE)[fnTimeOut], (DT_DATE)[fnTimeIn])/60) 
     + ":" + 
     (DT_STR,3,1252)(DATEDIFF("mi", (DT_DATE)[fnTimeOut], (DT_DATE)[fnTimeIn])%60)
)`

---

I'm trying to get my head around Derived Column expression syntax within SSIS (2012) but having a hard time. What I'm trying to do is create a new column that takes two dates and finds the difference between them `(DATEDIFF)` but in the format of DD:HH:MM. I know the formula I need to use, but my syntax is way off according to the compiler.

`(DT_WSTR,100,1252)(
    (DATEDIFF("mi", [fnTimeOut], [fnTimeIn] )/1440) + ":" + 
    (DATEDIFF("mi", [fnTimeOut] , [fnTimeIn])/60) + ":" + 
    (DATEDIFF("mi", [fnTimeOut] , [fnTimeIn])%60)
)`

I've tried applying the `DT_WSTR` to all 3 `DATEDIFF`s individually to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I dun goof'd?

Comment: THe SSIS expression editor is lame. I suggest you pre-calc the results in the source query and add the results as extra columns. Then you can actually check your result in real time

Comment: Its just a bit more strong typed than you expect.. I would take that rather than it not show errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of doing what you want at the source SQL level:

```
SELECT C1, C2,
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),
    REPLACE(
        RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(16),C2-C1,120),8),
        ' ',':'
        ) 
) DDHHMM
FROM 
( 
  -- sample data 
  SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-01-01 09:15:07') C1, 
  CONVERT(DATETIME,'2014-01-01 15:37:02') C2
) F
```

Note the HHMMSS field is a `NVARCHAR` (`DT_WSTR` in SSIS language). Are you certain you want to store your data as `NVARCHAR`  or do you want to store it in a more suitable format (i.e. `DATETIME`) and just format it a certain way later on?

I'm not sure how this one will work when the difference is more than one month. Is that something you need to allow for?

If you are having hassles with `DT_WSTR` I suggest you ensure your target tables are `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`, and also cast to `VARCHAR` in your source query. It saves loads of messing about in derived column casting back and forth between `DT_STR` and `DT_WSTR`

`NVARCHAR` is a way of basically storing foreign characters (it's much more complicated than that but thats the basics). If you don't have this requirement stick to VARCHAR.

Quite often the SSIS derived column task it totally unecessary because the data can be transformed back in the source SQL query, and it's one less piece of metadata to worry about.

Comment: I was thinking of doing it that way, but didn't want to overly complicate the process flow, so I just went with the expressions as above. And yeah, Im sure I want it in varchar, as that format can take into account over 24 hours duration because it includes the days. Just read your edit, I actually got an error in my destination. cannot convert between Unicode and non-Unicode strings. Would changing the datatype of the column in the destination to NVARCHAR correct the issue?

Comment: I thought the destination was already NVARCHAR. Are you saying it's VARCHAR? If so, change `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8),` to `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),` and see if that helps. In my opinion, the more logic in the database and the less in the package the simpler it is.... just my opinion.

Comment: Ended up just doing it at the SQL Level, made things much more smoother. Had to use a completely different SQL statement though, but your SQL got me started. Thanks buddy